# Invalid CSRF Token found for request

Tags: angular, cookies, spring-security, csrf, x-xsrf-token

My Security Configuration in Spring:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                    .cors()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/save")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**")
                    .hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .deleteCookies("XSRF-TOKEN")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
```

I am using Angular 6 on the front-end. I am doing a **POST** on the endpoint `/logout`. I can see the `JSESSIONID` and the `XSRF` cookies being sent on the request (using the developer tools in Chrome).

However, on the console of the Spring Server Side Application I get the following stack-trace:

```
Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8009/logout
```

...and the logout request fails.

I cannot understand why the XSRF token is not being updated (if that is so), or why the token is invalid.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cousl you add the screenshot (with the request/response including the headers) 
 of your dev tool?